# How to get fields from another section?

Tags: matrix, entry, sections

I need to get data from fields from another section. 
My code is:

```
        {% for kontaktEntry in craft.entries.section('kontakt').entry.kontakter %}
            <div>
                <a href="{{ kontaktEntry.epost }}">
                    {% set image = kontaktEntry.bilde.first() %}
                    {% if image %}
                        <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" width="100" height="100" alt="{{kontaktEntry.navn}}"/>
                    {% endif %}
                    <h3 class="center">{{ kontaktEntry.navn }}</h3>
                    {{ kontaktEntry.stilling }}
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

kontakter is a matrix. I get nothing in output. What is wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure that `.entry` is a valid parameter? I think that `craft.entries.section('kontakt')` contains an array with entries, so maybe you you could do `.first` on it?

Comment: Thank you, Youniteus! You are right! Publish it as an answer, so it will be voted up. craft.entries.section('kontakt').first.kontakter is a correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that .entry is a valid parameter? I think that craft.entries.section('kontakt') contains an array with entries, so maybe you you could do .first on it, so basically I think you wanted to do this:

```
    {% for kontaktEntry in craft.entries.section('kontakt').first.kontakter %}
        <div>
            <a href="{{ kontaktEntry.epost }}">
                {% set image = kontaktEntry.bilde.first() %}
                {% if image %}
                    <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" width="100" height="100" alt="{{kontaktEntry.navn}}"/>
                {% endif %}
                <h3 class="center">{{ kontaktEntry.navn }}</h3>
                {{ kontaktEntry.stilling }}
            </a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```